# Choppy Video playback on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics, video

I tried to play videos in my computer which has Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But, the videos are not running smoothly. For example each dialogue and its corresponding scene are getting repeated over and over. Its really irritating.
My computer has  **NV118 / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)** graphics.
Please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Consider adding more details about your situation. For instance, have you tested video playback in another OS, what are your PC specs, etc?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, since I upgraded my system from 18.04 to 20.04. And the video playback was fine before upgrade. It is only after the upgrade I am seeing this error

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this was causing your problem, but was definitely causing mine, specifically, choppy video and animation playback. (Scrolling through pages, video playback, just about anything.)

It turns out it was the indicator-multiload or System Monitor in the app indicators toolbar. Turn it off fixed the problem and videos/animations run smoothly.

I did **not** experience video playback stuttering to the point where things were getting repeated. In this case, it might not be your solution.

Also posting it here in case someone else finds this question because they were experiencing the same issue I did.

Also, if you're craving a system-monitor experience without the same problem, using the Gnome Extension 'system-monitor' has been working fine for me!

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution on my mothers and my own computer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it!

Comment: That was also my problem. Solution: 1. `apt purge indicator-multiload`, 2. `apt install gnome-system-monitor` (log out/back again, start it manually, then choose options)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable persistence mode using:

`sudo nvidia-smi -p 1.`

[Persistence Mode is the term for a user-settable driver property that keeps a target GPU initialized even when no clients are connected to it.](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html#persistence-mode)

I did try to open by the option of "Launch using Dedicated Card" but it didn't seem to work

Also, the mentioned solution is persistent you need to re-run it after every reboot.